# What is a synonym for murder that implies it is not murder?

Tags: synonyms

I am writing a story in which the government kills children to prevent overpopulation. I want to find a word that the government could use, because obviously, they are not going to outright admit to the killling of children.

Comment: Get creative. start with "population density correction'. you'll find the term you want.

Comment: Khmer Rouge’s Year Zero was a fancy name for what was in fact genocide https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_Zero_(political_notion)

Comment: demographic realignment

Comment: @PaulDirac Lmao

Comment: Has you read/watched *The Giver*? That’s what they did with the lightest of siblings who were born simultaneously.

Comment: With pets, a longstanding euphemism has been that the liquidated pet "went to live on a farm." That could easily be adapted to say "went [or was taken] to live in in the country."

Comment: For what it's worth, *killing*, itself, does not necessitate *murder*. "She was killed by the fall from the roof." Here, neither the fall nor the roof *murdered* her.

Answer (score 1):

The kids are being [taken care of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_care_of).

It can be taken literally to mean looking after someone, but colloquially it can mean to kill someone.

Comment: No. A government might just sink to this level of practice, but they wouldn't risk comparison with say gangsters by using a similar register.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you're assuming that in this story the populace is aware of the synonymy of "taken care of" and "murdered". But over time maybe that definition has fallen out of use.

Comment: I'm assuming that we're not into (a) guessing what semantic shifts may take place over the next 1000 years,  and (b) assuming random fictional English changes, and thus must use modern accepted usages, and am answering in accordance.

Comment: +1 I just finished a book in which the fictional government (only a few years in the future) used exactly this euphemism to hide what they were actually doing. This was also mixed with "give them the care they need."

Answer (score 0):

You could coin a dark euphemistic sense of the phrase **weaned off**, which is already highly associated with children.

Comment: I can’t believe this answer was downvoted when it’s the only one that actually addresses death.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a creative and entirely ambiguous way to put it:

> We're preparing our children for a brighter future.

Alluding both to the bright lights of heaven that these poor children will no doubt see and the "brighter future" the government will supposedly achieve when it resolves its overpopulation problems.

Answer (score 0):

Historically autocratic governments would talk about relocating or resettling surplus population.

That let people pretend that nothing evil was happening, when in fact those relocation journeys were resulting in certain (concentration camps) or likely (Trail of Tears) death of most of the relocatees.